# Writing Conditionals without using 'if' in python

Tags: python

I came across this problem statement in 'Think Python' book by Allan Downey:

> Write a boolean function called *is_after* that takes two Time objects, `t1` and `t2`, and returns *True* if `t1` follows `t2` chronologically and *False* otherwise. **Challenge:** *don't use an `if` statement.*

I wrote this code which seems to work fine:

```py
class Time:
    def __init__(self , hour , min , sec):
        self.hour = hour
        self.min = min
        self.sec = sec

def is_after(t1 , t2):
    if t1.hour > t2.hour:
        return True
    elif t1.hour == t2.hour:
        if t1.min > t2.min:
            return True
        elif t1.min == t2.min:
            if t1.sec > t2.sec:
                return True
            else:
                return False
        else:
            return False
    else:
        return False
```

But the author challenges the reader to accomplish the comparison without using a conditional operator. I can't imagine how can a comparison even be done without using `if/else` statements.

Comment: You can return the result of a comparison: `return a < b`

Comment: Your code already does comparisons. You should experiment with printing them out to see what you get.

Comment: This chain of conditions can be converted to comparisons. Think about when you want to return `True`: Either `t1.hour < t2.hour` ***or*** `t1.hour == t2.hour` ***and*** `t1.min < t2.min` ....

Comment: @Tomerikoo will follow your advice on future questions. thanks!

Comment: why are you not using the datetime module?  @Jenkins

Comment: @Nk03 I think you meant not instead of now in your comment !

Comment: yep @Programmer

Comment: Isn't your logic reversed? It says *"returns True if `t1` follows `t2` chronologically and False otherwise"* but you return `True` when `t1.hour < t2.hour`...

Comment: @Tomerikoo yeah you are correct! *t1* should *come after* *t2* for a logical `True` according to the problem statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can calculate the total seconds of the time, and return if t1 > t2

```Python
def is_after(t1, t2):
  t1_sec = 3600 * t1.hour + 60 * t1.min + t1.sec
  t2_sec = 3600 * t2.hour + 60 * t2.min + t2.sec
  return t1_sec > t2_sec
```

Answer (score 3):

Taking advantage of how tuple compare works, the following would be equivalent to your posted code.

```
def is_after(t1, t2):
    return (t1.hour, t1.minute, t1.second) > (t2.hour, t2.minute, t2.second)
```

Answer (score -2):

What about Ternary operators? [More info](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/ternary_operators.html)

Something like:

```py
return (false, true)[t1.hour < t2.hour]
```

Comment: you can expand it to do so

Comment: Also why not just `return t1.hour < t2.hour`?

Comment: in this case there's no difference but if you needed to not use a if statement to result in two different values ternary operators would be the way.